# What should I do with some answers I provided that probably are irrelevant to the questions asked?

Tags: support, answers

I was going through the list of answers I provided and some of them are not at all what the questioners were expecting; I'm making this assumption based on the accepted answers. Is it okay to flag them for deletion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yessir!

I believe you also can delete answers that you wrote and weren't accepted, or that don't require a moderator flag to do so.

Thanks for being interested on keeping the site clean. :-)

However, you can't delete more than five answers per day.

Answer (score 4):

### Delete Answers *If* They Won't Help Anyone

It's good to delete answers if they're no good. Just remember: if an answer **may help others, besides the OP**, it is usually a good thing to have around. (See [this MSO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37742/185080).)

Just as you can (and should) delete unworthy answers when you find them to be unworthy, you can also undelete worthy answers if you find you've deleted something that you think ought to exist.

(Deleted answers do not appear in your profile, though. But if you know of a good answer of yours that you'd like to undelete, you can often get help from others to find it.)